# Expected Colon at line 7, col 5

Tags: css, error-code

I'm currently working on a css file and I keep getting this error message. I'm new to html and coding in general, so sorry if this is a dumb question. I added a colon where the error message said I needed to but to no avail.

```
body {
font-family:garamond;
color:#cc4864;
background-color:#f5bdc6;
font-size:32px; 
text-align:center;
h2 {
border-style: dashed;
border-width: 3px;
border-left-width: 10px;
border-right-width: 10px;
border-color: red;

}
```

Comment: Close `body` with `}` before `h2`.

Answer (score 1):

Respect indentation, you'll find error yourself.

```
body {
    font-family:garamond;
    color:#cc4864;
    background-color:#f5bdc6;
    font-size:32px; 
    text-align:center;
}
h2 {
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-left-width: 10px;
    border-right-width: 10px;
    border-color: red;
}
```